# How to perform loop condition for a series based on previous term?

Tags: matlab

For instance I got a function of y = x + 1 goes under an iteration, how am I able to make the program to stop when the relative value is less than a value let say 0.0001. The relative value is defined as,

when x=1, y=2 ; x=2, y=3; x=3, y=4; so on and so forth. Then,

relative value of y (when x=2) = (3-2)/3 = 0.333333

This process is repeating until the relative value is less than 0.0001.

The problem now is how can I defined the current y value and the previous y value so that I could put it the loop condition something like

```
x = input('enter initial value of x');
while abs((current y-previous y)/current y) < 0.0001
y = 1 + x
end
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
x = input('enter initial value of x');
previousy = x;
currenty = x+1;

while( abs((currenty-previousy)/currenty) >= 0.0001)
    previousy = currenty;
    currenty = currenty+1;
end
```

Comment: Thanks. What's the `input` for, BTW?

Comment: based on OP's question, I'm guessing it's for a command prompt for the user to select an initial value, but I don't see the use, it's in the Matlab doc

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need any user input here nor a loop, your approach is not really native to MATLAB.

My suggestion for a solution would not include a loop, but rather look like this:

```
x = 1:1e5;                                  %// Values of x
y = x + 1;                                  %// Corresponding values of y
idx = find([NaN diff(y)] ./ y < 0.0001, 1); %// First index satisfying condition
currenty = y(idx)                           %// Value of y at that index
```

which would yield `currenty = 10001`.